# Pop shell in Ubuntu 20.04.03. Active window jumps to the end of stack

Tags: tiling

I have installed Pop shell in Ubuntu 20.04.03 after experiencing its might in Pop OS. I have two windows, one containing a browser (LEFT) and the other containing a stack (RIGHT) of two apps [VS code (left) and the terminal (right)] inside it.

When I use VS code, the left in the stack and jump to browser, it is all fine. However, When I switch back from the browser to the stack, it Jumps to the terminal, which is at the right of the stack skipping VS code. I just want it to go to the immediate right, not the extreme right.

The active window is highlighted in Lime Green.

Before switching to browser:
[image: Before switching to browser]

Switches to browser fine:
[image: Switches correctly to browser]

Jumps to Terminal at the extreme end when switching back:
[image: Jumps to Terminal at the extreme end when switching back]

Comment: It may help if you provide details on how you added it; if you added it via *deb* package then you're no longer using a Ubuntu system in my experience (but a mix of Ubuntu & off-topic Pop OS, & you've made your system more Pop OS, as Ubuntu *release-upgrade* tools will likely break your system now)

Comment: @guiverc I am sorry I didn't provide the info beforehand, I am very new to linux and it's community. I followed the steps given in this article about installing pop shell in ubuntu [link](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/05/how-to-install-pop-shell-tiling.html)